# How to handle SharedPreferences in MVP pattern?

Tags: java, android, mvp

How should I handle SharedPreferences in Fragments/Activity? I think it is not good idea to handle it in Fragment just in onPause method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat SharedPreferences exactly like you would treat a Database. It's just a way to save data, so it should be associated with Presenter, and not the View (Fragment/Activity/Custom View)

For example, you can create a wrapper class, like PreferenceAccessor or PreferenceDao, and pass it in the Presenters constructor.

Comment: You said - "Shared Prefs should be associated with Presenter" 
I somewhat doubt this.

Comment: and why is that? @eRaisedToX

Comment: because I read at most places that shared prefs fit to model in MVP pattern.., If I am right...